# Can't update global variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, global-variables

Can't seem to find an answer to this. I can't change a variable with my function and interact with it outside of the function. Here is my code:

```
    var secondsLeft = 10;

    function deathCounter() {
        secondsLeft
        if(secondsLeft > 0) {
            secondsLeft--;
            $('#deathCounter').text(secondsLeft);
            setTimeout(deathCounter, 1000);
            console.log('inside function: ' + secondsLeft)
        }
    }
    console.log('outside function: ' + secondsLeft);
```

It currently only updates the outside function once and then every second inside the function. But i wan't it to update outside of the function too. How can i do that?

Comment: what's the deal with 'secondsLeft' all by itself as the first line in the function?

Comment: Sorry, but you're wrong. It's updating the outer variable. You can easily see this, after the above code runs your global `secondsLeft` is 0. The problem is that you're only outputting the outer variable once.

Comment: and can you explain how you determine what is updating "outside of the function"?

Comment: I think it's working, you're just seeing the output for "outside function" before anything else; that logging statement runs immediately, not *after* `deathCounter()` is executed. Can you show how you use the above code?

Comment: where you call your `deathCounter` function? P.S remove the lonely `secondsLeft`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var secondsLeft = 10;
setTimeout(deathCounter, 1000);
    function deathCounter() {
        if(secondsLeft > 0) {
            secondsLeft--;
            $('#deathCounter').text(secondsLeft);
            setTimeout(deathCounter, 1000);
            console.log('inside function: ' + secondsLeft);
        }
    }
    console.log('outside function: ' + secondsLeft);
```

You never called your function outside of the function. Tested on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xakij/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: That extra `secondsLeft` would not reset the variable if it's already defined globally and does not include an assignment operator (at least not in Chrome).

Comment: Yeah I guess it was just the function call not being made. Will update.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/muxev/2/edit?js,console)
Try with:

```
var secondsLeft = 10;

function deathCounter() {
  if(secondsLeft>0) {
      secondsLeft-- ; // note the -- here!
      $('#deathCounter').text(secondsLeft); // Now text will update correctly
      console.log('inside function: ' + secondsLeft); // and the log
      setTimeout(deathCounter, 1000);       
   }
}

console.log('outside function: ' + secondsLeft);

deathCounter();
```

Comment: When the code goes through the loop the first time the 10 and 9 are showed at the same time. The function would have to be called above to make it countdown correctly.